# Arch/Grub - Disable booting message

Tags: linux, boot, grub, arch-linux, hid

I just installed Arch Linux for the first time. I'd like to achieve just a black screen when booting until I'm asked for the login. I'm using *grub* as a boot loader. And added the line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="vga=current quiet loglevel=3 rd.udev.log-priority=3 splash`

to the `/etc/default/grub` and updated *grub*, but I still see the message like

> Booting >>Arch Linux<<

for a split second on startup (actually the text is german). I'm not 100% sure, whether this is printed by *grub*, but that's my current guess.

Does anybody have an idea how to troubleshoot this/hide the message?

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove that message, go into `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Scroll down until you see the line `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###`. Right below, you'll see something like this:

```
menuentry 'Arch Linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-cdb0b113-f657-4b1b-a8e9-3fd0fb2c55d2' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd1,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  AAF7-73DC
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root AAF7-73DC
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux linux-selinux ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-linux-selinux root=UUID=cdb0b113-f657-4b1b-a8e9-3fd0fb2c55d2 rw cryptdevice=/dev/sdb3:root security=selinux selinux=1 init=/usr/bin/e4rat-lite-preload
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /intel-ucode.img /initramfs-linux-selinux.img
}
```

Remove the lines that begin with `echo` and that boot message will be gone. Add `quiet` to your kernel parameters to disable boot messages in the kernel.

Comment: the answer given by @h313 does not actually achieve what was asked for. Note that the two `echo` statements begin with "Loading", and not with "Booting". That one is hard-coded into GRUB and in order to remove it, GRUB will need to be patched and recompiled. Alternatively, you may get lucky with https://github.com/ccontavalli/grub-shusher/, which doesn't seem to be maintained, though.

Comment: This file starts with "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE". Because it is auto-generated. Look in `/etc/grub.d/` for the files from which it is generated, but I guess those belong to packages, and those may be overwritten as well.